# Cancellation problem when using nested future on Java

Tags: java, futuretask

If the `Future` is nested for different jobs is created and given the same timeout for both `Future`, the main `Future` is not canceled. But if the timeout for the child `Future` is less than the main `Future`, it can be canceled.

What is the reason of this?

My example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    Future<Object> main= service.submit(()->{
        Future<Object> child= service.submit(()->{                
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                System.out.println("child future is running...");
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }                
            return 0;
        });
        try{
            child.get(10,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }catch(Exception we){
            System.out.println("child future cancelled.");
            child.cancel(true); 
        }            
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
            System.out.println("main future is running...");
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        return 0;
    });
    try{
        main.get(10,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }catch(Exception we){
        System.out.println("main future cancelled.");
        main.cancel(true);           
    }
}
```